# Fill the fields of a form automatically after it is loaded, then rinse and repeat

Tags: javascript, forms

I am a complete noob to programming so call me a lazy loser or whatever you want, I am merely looking for some direction, not straight up answers.

I need to fill out a bunch of forms with random words. I can construct the program to find the ID's and fill them in, but how can I make it so when the page is reloaded it continues the same thing?

For context: The page is setup so that once I click submit on the form, it will just load a new form.

Comment: lazylozer: *"...reloaded it continues the same thing?"* Normal behavior on a submitted form is that the data is gone from the form. This "same thing" you speak of is vague, please explain the behavior desired and the behavior you are actually getting instead.

Comment: @zer00ne it will literally just load the same type of form (three answer boxes) once you click submit on the one you just filled out

Comment: So the content is persistent after clicking the submit button? You need to provide a [mcve]